# c# Using Parameters.AddWithValue in SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, parameters, ado.net, sqldataadapter

How can I use Parameters.AddWithValue with an SqlDataAdapter. Below searching codes.

```
var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM annotations WHERE annotation LIKE '%"+txtSearch.Text+"%'", _mssqlCon.connection);
var dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

I rewrote the code like this:

```
SqlDataAdapter da;
da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM annotations WHERE annotation LIKE '%@search%'", _mssqlCon.connection);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search",txtSearch.Text);
var dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

but it failed.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The string used to initialize the **SqlDataAdapter** becomes the value for the `CommandText` property inside the [SelectCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the SqlDataAdapter.
You could add parameters to that command with this code

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM annotations WHERE annotation LIKE @search",
                        _mssqlCon.connection);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search","%" + txtSearch.Text + "%");
```

- First, remove the single quotes around the parameter placeholder.
- Second, add the wildcard character directly to the Value parameter of
  AddWithValue

You have asked to use **AddWithValue**, but remember that, while it is a useful shortcut, there are also numerous drawbacks and all well documented.

- First: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) where the
  author discuss how *AddWithValue* could be the source for wrong results in your
  queries
- Second: [How Data Access Code Affects Database Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx) where
  the author presents evidences of strong performance problems for
  *AddWithValue*

So, the same code without **AddWithValue** and using the [Object and Collection Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) syntax could be written as

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM annotations WHERE annotation LIKE @search",
                        _mssqlCon.connection);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "@search",
    Value = "%" + txtSearch.Text + "%",
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
    Size = 2000  // Assuming a 2000 char size of the field annotation (-1 for MAX)
});
```

and, an even more simplified and one liner version of the above is:

```
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@search",SqlDbType.NVarChar,2000).Value = "%" + txtSearch.Text + "%";
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add()` instead of `cmd.Parameters.Add()`, here's a sample for dealing with a stored procedure which takes two parameters and second one is a nullable int parameter:

```
public DataTable GetData(int par1, int? par2)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            string sql = "StoredProcedure_name";
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Par1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = par1;
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Par2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (object)par2?? DBNull.Value;

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "SourceTable_Name");

            DataTable dt = ds.Tables["SourceTable_Name"];

            //foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            //{
            //You can even manipulate your data here
            //}
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mySearchString = "Select * From test Where ([title] LIKE '%' + @title + '%')";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.VarChar, 120);
cmd.Parameters("@title").Value = TextBox1.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Repeater for show data

```
int queryString =int.Parse(Request.QueryString["Id"]);

SqlConnection conn =new SqlConnection("server=.; Database=Northwind; 
Integrated Security=true;");

try{
conn.Open();

SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ProductID, ProductName, UnitPrice, CategoryID FROM Products WHERE CategoryID =@CategoryID", conn);

dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@CategoryID", queryString);
                        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
                        QueryStringProductListRepeater.DataSource = dataSet;
                        QueryStringProductListRepeater.DataBind();
}

catch{
Response.Write("QueryStringProductListRepeater");
}

finally{
conn.Close();
}
```