# Rework using parameterized queries C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, parameterized-query

There is a lot of tutorials regarding parameterized queries but most of them involve using `SqlCommand`, the only thing my code accepts is `SqlDataAdapter` for my SQL command, anytime I try to instantiate it as a `SqlCommand` I get errors.

TL;DR
I either need guidance on how to rework this using parameterized queries or I need to know why my `SqlDataAdapter` line doesn't work as an `SqlCommand` line.

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Jake\Documents\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True;");

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From Login Where Username = '" + txtUsername.Text + "' and Password = '" + txtPassword.Text + "'", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
    {
        this.Hide();
        MessageBox.Show("LOGIN!");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("FAILED!");
    }
}
```

Comment: the sql commend is to run statements like insert and update because you dont need to return nothing. If you need to return something you need a sqldatadadapter.

Your query needs sqlparamenters, add them using @ParameterName and add the sql parameter to your sqldata adapter. If you keep your query like this you are vulnerable for sql injections and your code is not secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Parameters.AddWithValue` in SqlDataAdapter

```
    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParamName",value);
```

Check this: [c# Using Parameters.AddWithValue in SqlDataAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276602/c-sharp-using-parameters-addwithvalue-in-sqldataadapter)

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @marc_s not really, it always depend on the situation, but if needed , he can use `.Parameters.Add("@ParamName", DataTypeHere).Value = ValueHere`

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
   using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from user where username = @username and password = @pass", sqlConnect))
    {
        sqlDA.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = username;
sqlDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = password;

        sqlDA.Fill(dataTableVariable);
        return dataTableVariable;
    }
```

For your password remember to use a hash algorithm

This code is not tested. If you want the best performance you can explore execute scalar.

Comment: Can you elaborate on hash algorithm? Sorry I'm new to this and you've got my attention 8)

Comment: The hash is one way encryption and is used to encrypt password most of the time. When your system create the user the password is encrypted using your hash algorithm  (sha please) and then when the user wants to log in the password provided is converted to a hash a compared with the one stored in the database

Answer (score 1):

Try using parametrize query, it will avoids errors and sql injection
Once you have the reader you can use `HasRow()` to check if a record is returned

```
string conString = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "SELECT * FROM Login Where Username=@Username AND Password=@Password",
    con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);

        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRow())
            {
                if(reader.Read())
                {
                    var username = reader["Username"].ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //User does not exists
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

You will need to import some library:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Comment: Interesting this is totally new to me, ill have to mess around with this method of handling it, thank you for the help!

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Or since this query returns **one row, one column** only, it would be much simpler to use a  `SqlCommand cmd = ......` and then call `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` on it.....