# combobox population based on each other sql c#

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

i have 2 boxes, i'd like to populate the 1st from sql and the 2nd based on the first (querying sql too)

```
public void Country()
    {

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT CountryName FROM Country", conn))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);

                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr["CountryName"] = "";
                    dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
                    this.country.DisplayMember = "CountryName";
                    this.country.ValueMember = "CountryName";
                    this.country.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }

public void City()
    {

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT CityName FROM City", conn))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);

                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr["CityName"] = "";
                    dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
                    this.country.DisplayMember = "CityName";
                    this.country.ValueMember = "CityName";
                    this.country.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

T A B L E S

**Country**

PK CountryName

**City**

PK CityName

FK CountryName

I believe i should change City's SqlCommand, maybe a WHERE statement? so if Country1 is chosen, in the City box it only shows  City1, if Country2 then City2 and so on.
how can i sort this, anyone knows? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CityName FROM City where CountryName =@CountryName
```

Change the select statement with where clause as above,then you can set the parameter value using `this.country.SelectedValue`

You can load the second combobox on first combobox selelected index changed event. Call the `City()` inside first combobox selected index changed event with the where condition to filter city based on country

few links for related code:

[c# Using Parameters.AddWithValue in SqlDataAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276602/c-sharp-using-parameters-addwithvalue-in-sqldataadapter)

[Cascading ComboBox In Windows Application Using C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/009464/cascading-combobox-in-windows-application-using-c-sharp/)

Comment: thank you. don't have time to test it at the moment but will absolutely do and mark the answer good if worked!

Comment: @mihocu hope you understand the concept, given links will help you to do the coding your self.