# c# selecting all record with specific data on datatable

Tags: c#

I'm planning to select all rows in my datatable that has 'Dog' in column 2 without using keyword "WHERE" on my query. My guess is to try using DataRow and foreach but I'm not sure where to start. I filled my datatable with records coming from my database and this is what I've done so far.

```
   using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constring))
   {
   MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table1",con);
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   adp.Fill(dt);
   adp.Dispose();
   }
```

This is what my datatable looks like:

```
   Column1 Column2  Column3
   1       Dog      Labrador
   2       Dog      Chowchow
   3       Cat      Persian
   4       Cat      Stubby
   5       Dog      German Shepherd
```

Comment: Why you do not want to use `WHERE`? This is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter records when populating table using data adapter by modifying select query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE  Column2='Dog'
```

and second approach if you need to filter later then use this approach - [Creating a DataTable From a Query (LINQ to DataSet)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/creating-a-datatable-from-a-query-linq-to-dataset):

```
List<DataRow> result = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(row=> row.Field<string>("Column2") = "Dog").ToList();
```

You can filter records by using DataView and use the [RowFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.110).aspx) Property as below:

```
// Create a DataView
 DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
 // Filter by an expression. 
 dv.RowFilter = "Column2 = 'Dog'";
DataTable newTable = view.ToTable();
```

**References:**
[Creating a DataTable from a DataView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/creating-a-datatable-from-a-dataview)

Comment: Yay! I'm going to try this sir and as soon as it works I'm going to mark this as answer. you definitely get what I'm trying to accomplish. Thank you so much. I know how to use Where but I don't know how to do the same thing on datatable.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is easy to follow and understand.

Answer (score 1):

Use where to distinguish:

```
   using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constring))
   {
   MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table1,con);
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   adp.Fill(dt);
   IEnumerable<DataRow> query = adp.Where(x => x.Column2 == 'dog').ToList();

   DataTable filteredRows = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();

   adp.Dispose();
   }
```

Comment: I know how to do this sir and what I'm trying to do is to select from a datatable. the reason what I'm trying to do this is to feed my curiosity. I'm really sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a SQL [`WHERE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_(SQL)) clause. Always use [`SqlParameter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276602/c-sharp-using-parameters-addwithvalue-in-sqldataadapter) or similar to insert variables into a query (prevents potential [SQL injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) if parameter value is user provided).

```
string genusInput = "Dog"; // might be provided by user input later on

DataTable result = new DataTable();

using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constring)) {

    const string query = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Column2 = @genus";    
    var adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, con);
    adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@genus", genusInput);
    adp.Fill(result);
    adp.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constring))
   {
      MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table1",con);
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      adp.Fill(dt);
      adp.Dispose();

      DataRow[] dr=dt.select(“Column2=‘Dog’”);
  }
```

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create `where` statement in your query as below sample

```
   MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Column2='Dog'",con);
```