# read a table with uniqueidentifier ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms, uniqueidentifier

I want search in database and if the code is exist set ID equal by session[SID].
the ID of my table is `uniqueidentifier` and it has error. the error is on `r.read();`:

> Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier

Code:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string CodeReg = txtCodeReg.Text;

    Guid g = new Guid();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Db_Hospital;Integrated Security=True";

    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "Select CodeMeli From Tbl_Staff where (ID=@ID)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtCode.Text);

    SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    r.Read();

    if (r.HasRows)
    {
        Session["SID"] = g;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AddWithValue will create a parameter whose type is the type of the value passed. In your case this parameter is of type string. But to work correctly you should pass an uniqueidentifier instead.

```
if (!Guid.TryParse(txtCode.Text, out Guid result))
{
    Console.WriteLine("not a valid guid");
    return;
}
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = result;
```

In general you should try to avoid this AddWithValue because there are many undesiderable side effects. You can read about this scenario in

[Using Parameters.AddWithValue in SqlDataAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276602/c-sharp-using-parameters-addwithvalue-in-sqldataadapter)

Answer (score 0):

Another posible solution. Just convert the ID uniqueidentifier to VARCHAR(36).

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string CodeReg = txtCodeReg.Text;

    Guid g = new Guid();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Db_Hospital;Integrated Security=True";

    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "Select CodeMeli From Tbl_Staff where (CONVERT(VARCHAR(36),ID)=@ID)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtCode.Text);

    SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    r.Read();

    if (r.HasRows)
    {
        Session["SID"] = g;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure but probably this will make the index on the ID field (if any) unusable