# Filter data from sql with datetimepicker as "dd-MM-yyyy" format

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, filter, datetimepicker

I'm trying to filter data from datagirdview by using 2 datetimepicker. Everything goes well when I call a query at SQL server, but when I try to call the same query at c# winform app. I get this error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from chracter string."

Here is my sql query for test purposes:

```
select*from order where CONVERT(datetime, orderDate, 105) between convert(datetime,'01.07.2021',105) and CONVERT(datetime,'15.12.2021',105)
```

Everything works fine here
Here is my c# filtering code:

```
private void button23_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(UygulamaAyarlari.ConnectionString()))
            {
                Datepicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                Datepickler1.FormatCustom = "dd-MM-yyyy";
                Datepicker2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                Datepicker2.FormatCustom = "dd-MM-yyyy";
                MessageBox.Show(bunifuDatepicker1.Value.ToString());

                SqlDataAdapter sdf = new SqlDataAdapter("select* from order Where CONVERT(datetime, orderDate, 105)  between convert(datetime,'" + bunifuDatepicker1.Value.ToString()+ "',1905) and convert(datetime,'" + bunifuDatepicker2.ToString() + "',1905)", con);
                DataTable sd = new DataTable();
                sdf.Fill(sd);
                DatagridView1.DataSource = sd;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
        }
        
            
    }
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Calling `bunifuDatepicker1.Value.ToString();` is going to return the `DateTime` as text based on the system date/time format. A quick fix is to call `bunifuDatepicker1.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");`. However, the correct way is to add the parameters as the actual values, and NOT call `convert`.

Comment: And make `orderDate` column a datetime, not a varchar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276602/c-sharp-using-parameters-addwithvalue-in-sqldataadapter/13276651

Comment: By the way, format code 105 is `dd-mm-yyyy`. [You should really use 104](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), which is `dd.mm.yyyy`. Don't store dates as varchars; if someone goes an inserts bad data into the column, it'll keep crashing the queries until it is removed

Answer (score 2):

1. Name your controls after you drop them on a form. For you to even have a button handler called `button23_Click`, implying you have a UI with at least 23 buttons named only numerically, is crazy
2. Your database `orderDate` should be a datetime2 column. Let's assume you make it a datetime2(3)
3. Your code should then look like this:

```
    //button name and click handler name updated
    private void GetOrdersCreatedBetweenButton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(UygulamaAyarlari.ConnectionString()))
            {

                SqlDataAdapter sdf = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from order Where orderDate between @f and @t", con);
                sdf.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@f", SqlDbType.DateTime2) { Scale = 3, Value = Datepicker1.Value });
                sdf.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@t", SqlDbType.DateTime2) { Scale = 3, Value = Datepicker2.Value });

                DataTable sd = new DataTable();
                sdf.Fill(sd);
                DatagridView1.DataSource = sd;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
        }
        
            
    }
```

If you make `orderDate` a datetime, or a datetime2 with a different scale (number of milliseconds precision) adjust the `Scale = x` in the parameters accordingly