# Error when using transaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqltransaction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction error in my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648718/executenonquery-requires-the-command-to-have-a-transaction-error-in-my-code)

```
strSQL = "insert into............";

SqlTransaction objSqlTransaction = Master.objSqlDbComm.SqlConnectionObject.BeginTransaction();
try
{
    Master.objSqlDbComm.ExecuteNonQuery(strSQL);
    objSqlTransaction.Commit();
}
catch(Exception)
{
    objSqlTransaction.Rollback();
}
finally
{
    objSqlTransaction.Dispose();
}
```

When I use above code getting error

> *ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized.*

Comment: You need to set reference of Transaction object `objSqlTransaction` to `command.Transaction` property.

Comment: When you get an error message, type it into google and click the first link that leads to stack overflow. Chances are above average that that's your answer!

Comment: why i have to create new sqlcommand object.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to give command object to `ExecuteNonQuery`

do something like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(your_sqlText, your_sqlcon, your_sqlTrans);  

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: why i have to create new sqlcommand object.

Comment: @lax: because executenonquery is method of command object