# Call multiple SQL Server stored procedures in a transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, asynchronous, .net-3.5, transactions

For usage in my current project I've created a class that allows me to call SQL Server async.

My code looks like this:

```
internal class CommandAndCallback<TCallback, TError>
{
    public SqlCommand Sql { get; set; }
    public TCallback Callback { get; set; }
    public TError Error { get; set; }
}

class MyCodes:SingletonBase<MyCodes>
{
    private static string _connString = @"Data Source=MyDB;Initial Catalog=ED;Integrated Security=True;Asynchronous Processing=true;Connection Timeout=0;Application Name=TEST";

    private MyCodes() { }

    public void SetSystem(bool production)
    {
        _connString =
            string.Format(@"Data Source=MyDB;Initial Catalog={0};Integrated Security=True;Asynchronous Processing=true;Connection Timeout=0;Application Name=TEST", production ? "ED" : "TEST_ED");
    }

    public void Add(string newCode, Action<int> callback, Action<string> error)
    {
        var conn = new SqlConnection(_connString);
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = @"ADD_CODE";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@NEW", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = newCode;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@NewId", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        try
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error(ex.ToString());
            return;
        }

        var ar = new CommandAndCallback<Action<int>, Action<string>> { Callback = callback, Error = error, Sql = cmd };
        cmd.BeginExecuteReader(Add_Handler, ar, CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    }

    private static void Add_Handler(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var ar = (CommandAndCallback<Action<int>, Action<string>>)result.AsyncState;
        if (result.IsCompleted)
        {
            try
            {
                ar.Sql.EndExecuteReader(result);
                ar.Callback(Convert.ToInt32(ar.Sql.Parameters["@NewId"].Value));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ar.Error(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ar.Error("Error executing SQL");
        }
    }

public void Update(int codeId, string newCode, Action callback, Action<string> error)
    {
        var conn = new SqlConnection(_connString);
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE_CODE";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CODE_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = codeId;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@NEW", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = newCode;

        try
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error(ex.ToString());
            return;
        }

        var ar = new CommandAndCallback<Action, Action<string>> { Callback = callback, Error = error, Sql = cmd };
        cmd.BeginExecuteReader(Update_Handler, ar, CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    }

    private static void Update_Handler(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var ar = (CommandAndCallback<Action, Action<string>>)result.AsyncState;
        if (result.IsCompleted)
        {
            try
            {
                ar.Sql.EndExecuteReader(result);
                ar.Callback();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ar.Error(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ar.Error("Error executing SQL");
        }
    }

}
```

This may look like too much of code, but it lets me call it as so:

```
private void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MyCodes.Instance.Add("Test",Success,Error)
}

private void Success(int newId)
{
   MessageBox.Show(newId.ToString(), "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}

private void Error(string error)
{
   MessageBox.Show(error, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Above code works just fine for me, I'm able to do every call async.

Problem that I have right now is to do multiple calls as transaction - I would like to update 2 codes and add one new.

Normally I would call update, then in success handler call second update, and in handler to second update I would call add that would return new id.

Something like:

```
-UPDATE CODE
 |-UPDATE CODE
   |-ADD CODE (only this one return something)
```

But I would like to call all of those as transaction, so if add code would break updates would rollback.

Question:

Is it possible to call multiple async queries as a transaction?

Can I call my above methods as transaction or do I must create separate method to call my procedures as one? (I would like to avoid this one because it's just copying the same code from one method to another)

I would like to add that I use .NET 3.5 so await and other nice features aren't an option.

Comment: Unfortunatly, to wrap all of your procedures in one transaction you will have to execute them one after the other. You will otherwise end up having a transaction per execution.

Comment: LukeHennerly - Could You help me to build method that will call multiple procedures as one? Ideally it would take list of codes to update and code to add as parameters and of course it should be called async as above

Answer (score 20):

```
  string cnnString =WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(cnnString);
    SqlTransaction transaction;

    cnn.Open();
    transaction = cnn.BeginTransaction();

    try
    {

        // Command Objects for the transaction
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("sproc1", cnn);
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("sproc2", cnn);

        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Param1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50));
        cmd1.Parameters["@Param1"].Value = paramValue1;

        cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Param2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50));
        cmd1.Parameters["@Param2"].Value = paramValue2;

        cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Param3", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50));
        cmd2.Parameters["@Param3"].Value = paramValue3;

        cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Param4", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50));
        cmd2.Parameters["@Param4"].Value = paramValue4;

        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

        transaction.Commit();
    }

    catch (SqlException sqlEx)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
    }

    finally
    {
        cnn.Close();
        cnn.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying in such old question :) In free time I'll check Your solution. Right now I'm migrating everything to .NET 4.5 so I'll implement this feature while I'll be creating my DB access class.

Comment: Also mention `SqlCommand.Transaction` this way `SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("sproc1", cnn, transaction);` or this way `cmd1.Transaction = transaction` in case you get the error message: _ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction. The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized_. Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10649035/1369235

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it is possible. Simply call [`SqlConnection.BeginTransaction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86773566.aspx) before your first call. Make sure you assign the returned [`SqlTransaction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.aspx) object to each [`SqlCommand.Transaction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.transaction.aspx) in the chain and call [`SqlTransaction.Commit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.commit.aspx) at the end.

Comment: i tried this with a delete which has to delete some foreigen key first(separat stored procedures) and i doesn't get it to run, but with save and update it works fine

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Command
{
    public string sql { get; set; }
    public CommandType cmdType { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> parameter { get; set; } = null;
}

    private Command insertInvoice(Invoice invoice)
    {
        try
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> parameterLocal = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            parameterLocal.Add("p_customerId", invoice.customerId);
            parameterLocal.Add("p_invoiceNo", invoice.invoiceNo);
            parameterLocal.Add("p_invoiceDate", invoice.invoiceDate);
            parameterLocal.Add("p_invoiceAmount", invoice.invoiceAmount);                
            parameterLocal.Add("p_withInvoice", invoice.withInvoice);

            return (new Command { sql = "sp_insertInvoice", cmdType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameter = parameterLocal });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private Command insertInvoiceModel(InvoiceModel invoiceModel)
    {
        try
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> parameterLocal = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            parameterLocal.Add("p_invoiceNo", invoiceModel.invoiceNo);
            parameterLocal.Add("p_model", invoiceModel.model);
            parameterLocal.Add("p_quantity", invoiceModel.quantity);
            parameterLocal.Add("p_unitPrice", invoiceModel.unitPrice);

            return (new Command { sql = "sp_insertInvoiceModel", cmdType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameter = parameterLocal });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

 List<Command> commandList = new List<Command>();

 cmd = insertInvoice(invoicesave);

 commandList.Add(cmd);

 cmd = insertInvoiceModel(invoiceModelSave);

 commandList.Add(cmd);

        try
        {
            erplibmain.erpDac.runOleDbTransaction(commandList);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    public void runOleDbTransaction(List<Command> commandList)
    {
        OleDbConnection erpConnection = new OleDbConnection(ErpDalMain.connectionstring);
        erpConnection.Open();

        OleDbCommand erpCommand = erpConnection.CreateCommand();
        OleDbTransaction erpTrans;

        // Start a local transaction
        erpTrans = erpConnection.BeginTransaction();
        // Assign transaction object for a pending local transaction
        erpCommand.Connection = erpConnection;
        erpCommand.Transaction = erpTrans;

        try
        {
            foreach (Command cmd in commandList)
            {
                erpCommand.CommandText = cmd.sql;
                erpCommand.CommandType = cmd.cmdType;

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in cmd.parameter)
                {
                    erpCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(entry.Key, entry.Value);
                }

                erpCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                erpCommand.Parameters.Clear();
            }

            erpTrans.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            try
            {
                erpTrans.Rollback();
            }
            catch (OleDbException ex)
            {
                if (erpTrans.Connection != null)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }

            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            erpConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```