# Transaction starting in stored procedure 1 and ending in SP3

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I have several stored procedures in a job, and In one of them I Begin a transaction to delete some rows and if rows are greater than 10 then I Roll back. however if there are not I don't want to commit straight away, because 2 stored procedure later I do something similar. however if count is greater than 10 in this instance I want it rolled back all the way to when I stared the transaction (two stored procedures ago)

Is it possible to start a transaction in a store procedure and have multiple roll backs and Commit right at the end somewhere or do I have to put all the code into 1 store procedure to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds incredibly prone to failure.

Regardless, you will need to start the transaction in your code then, while using the same connection, execute the procs.  The code would then commit or rollback once all the procs have executed.

Assuming this is `c#`, see the following question for answers: [Call multiple SQL Server stored procedures in a transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431285/call-multiple-sql-server-stored-procedures-in-a-transaction)

Answer (score 0):

You can  write several stored procedures and then execute them as nested.
You can declare variables in order to get the result and use if statement to commit or rais error for catch block or rollback transaction