# TransactionScope and transactions included in nested stored procedures

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I'm using TransactionScope in my C# code. I will try to simplify as much as I  can .

```
public void ProcessStrings(...)
{
    ...
    using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        ...
        if(someCondition)  
        {   
            try
            {  
                DeleteSomeStrings(...);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //log error
                ...
                throw;
            }
        }

        ...

        try
        {
            UpdateSomeStrings(...);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //log error
            ...
            throw;
        }

        ...

        transactionScope.Complete();
    }
    ...
}
```

The *DeleteSomeStrings* and *UpdateSomeStrings* methods call two stored procedures through ADO.NET. I need to use explicit transaction handling into these stored procedures as well because they are also called from other contexts:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteSomeStrings]
...
--parameter list
...
AS
BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRAN
    ...
    COMMIT TRAN
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    ...
    ROLLBACK 
    ...
    RAISERROR(...)
END CATCH
```

and the second one has a similar structure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateSomeStrings]
...
--parameter list
...
AS
BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRAN
    ...
    COMMIT TRAN
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    ...
    ROLLBACK 
    ...
    RAISERROR(...)
END CATCH
```

The problem is when *DeleteSomeStrings* succeeds and UpdateSomeStrings fails, the data that was processed in *DeleteSomeStrings* still gets committed. It looks like the TransactionScope is ignored in this scenario. I would expect everything to be rolled back. Is this the normal behavior and if so why?

Comment: When you are executing the first stored procedure, try using `rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` if rowsAffexted is Zero, no point in executing the second SP

Comment: have a look a this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431285/call-multiple-sql-server-stored-procedures-in-a-transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it work by using *SqlTransaction* instead of *TransactionScope* and passing the same connection and transaction to the command objects that were used to execute the two stored procedures. It seams  *TransactionScope* cannot be used in this scenario. Thanks for your comments.